# python program to fade an image in radial direction

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to write a program which fades an image in radial direction. which means as we move away from the centre of the image, the pixels fade to black. For this, I have written five different functions:

---

```
center: returns coordinate pair (center_y, center_x) of the image center.
radial_distance: returns for image with width w and height h an array with shape (h,w), where the number at index (i,j) gives the euclidean distance from the point (i,j) to the center of the image.
scale: returns a copy of the array 'a' (or image) with its elements scaled to be in the given range.
radial_mask: takes an image as a parameter and returns an array with same height and width filled with values between 0.0 and 1.0.
radial_fade: returns the image multiplied by its radial mask.
```

---

The program is:

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def center(a):
    y, x = a.shape[:2]
    return ((y-1)/2,(x-1)/2)   # note the order: (center_y, center_x)

def radial_distance(b):
    h, w = b.shape[:2]
    y, x = center(b)
    o = b[:h,:w,0]
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            o[i,j] = np.sqrt((y-i)**2 + (x-j)**2)
    return o

def scale(c, tmin=0.0, tmax=1.0):

    """Returns a copy of array 'a' with its values scaled to be in the range
[tmin,tmax]."""
    mini, maxi = c.min(), c.max()
    if maxi == 0:
        return 0
    else:

        m = (tmax - tmin)/(maxi - mini)

        f = tmin - m*mini
        return c*m + f

def radial_mask(d):
    f = radial_distance(d)
    g = scale(f, tmin=0.0, tmax=1.0)
   # f = g[:,:,0]
    n = 1.0 - g
    return n

def radial_fade(l):
    f, g = l.shape[:2]
    q = l[:f,:g,0]
    return q * radial_mask(l)
image = plt.imread("src/painting.png")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
masked = radial_mask(ima)
faded = radial_fade(ima)
ax[0].imshow(ima)
ax[1].imshow(masked)
ax[2].imshow(faded)
plt.show()
```

---

there is something wrong somewhere in the code as it does not do the expected job.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that in

```
o = b[:h,:w,0]
```

you're using the same precision as the image that may be integers (e.h. `uint8`).

You should use for example

```
o = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
```